# 'Break' Outside Loop - Python - Number Guess Game

Tags: python, python-3.4

I keep getting this error for the second break command, not the first. Why is this happening?
It says:

```
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
import easygui

secrets = random.randint(1, 200)
secret = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = 0
tries = 0

easygui.msgbox("""AHOY! I'm the Dreaded Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret! It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 10 tries.""")

while guess != secret and tries < 10:
    guess = easygui.integerbox("What's yer guess, matey?")
    if not guess: break
    if guess < secret:
        easygui.msgbox(str(guess) + " is too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        easygui.msgbox(str(guess) + " is too high, landlubber!")
    tries = tries + 1

if guess == secret:
    easygui.msgbox("Avast! Ye got it! My secret is: **** ** ****! NO MATTER WHAT ****** SAYS, **** *****!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

else:
    easygui.msgbox("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!")
    easygui.msgbox("Now, since ye lost, ye can try 1-50.")

    while guess != secrets and tries < 15:
        guess = easygui.integerbox("What's yer guess, matey?")
        if not guess: break
    if guess < secrets:
        easygui.msgbox(str(guess) + " is too low, ye scurvy dog!")

    elif guess > secrets:
        easygui.msgbox(str(guess) + " is too high, landlubber!")
    tries = tries + 1
```

The second "if not guess: break" is what the error is about.
Can somebody explain?

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: what error? And don't post code as an image, copy-paste the actual text (there's a code-block formatting option when editing a question).

Comment: that break is not in a loop.

Comment: Do *NOT* post images of code. Please post your code in the question itself *as formatted text*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error description:

```
>>> if True: break
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Make sure that you indent that entire section of code such that it is part of the `while` loop